# Pyserial readline() and wait until receives a value to continue

Tags: python, arduino, readline, pyserial

I'm using Pyserial to communicate between python and arduino. I have to wait until the arduino actions are executed before continuing my python loop. I have the arduino print out "done" after it completes its actions. How would I check for this using readline(). I'm trying this at the moment however it never breaks out of the loop:

```
arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=.2)

for coordinate in coordinates:
    c = str(coordinate[0]) + ", " + str(coordinate[1])
    arduino.write(bytes(c, 'utf-8'))
    while arduino.readline() != "Done":
          print(arduino.readline())
```

```
void loop() {
  while (!Serial.available()){
    MotorControl(100);
  }
  MotorControl(0);
  String coordinates = Serial.readString();
  int i = coordinates.indexOf(',');
  int x = coordinates.substring(0, i).toInt();
  int y = coordinates.substring(i+1).toInt();

//there will be some other actions here

  Serial.print("Done");
```

In the terminal I can see that it prints out b'Done'however I don't know how to reference this in my python while loop.

Comment: You are only checking every other line from the Arduino for equality to "Done".  The other half (and *only* that other half) are simply being printed, without otherwise being examined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `arduino.readline()` is returning `bytes` but you're comparing it to a `str`, so the result is always `False`:

```
>>> print("Done" == b"Done")
False
```

The simplest solution would be to change `"Done"` to `b"Done"`, like this:

```
    while arduino.readline() != b"Done":
```